# Power Pivot - how to filter values in Columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, data-analysis, powerpivot

I guess i need your help.
I'm sitting in front of a very little excel file.
The file contains 4 columns of information:

1. Material group (60 Materialgroups)
2. Budget (different Budgets depending on the period)
3. Period (values 3,4,6)

What i would like to do is to calculate the total SUM of each period (3,4,6) of the budgets with some measures in power pivot. The final result of this operation should be like:

Measure 1: XXX€ in Period 3
Measure 2: YYY€ in Period 4
Measure 3: ZZZ€ in Period 6

Then I would like to calculate the percentage deviation of the individual periods.

Why am i doing it like that? Because i would like to understand DAX Functions.

What i understand is, that i can use the CALCULATE and SUM Funtions. But i do not understand how to set a "filter" for the Values 3,4,6.

Your support would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alright, i was able to solve this problem, but now, i'm facing the problem, that I cannot calculate the percentage deviation...

Comment: What do you mean by percentage deviation?

Comment: Well i would like to calculate the differences between the periods as percentages. Period 3 is like 100%, Period 4 is like +20% and Period 6 is like +10% compared to Period 3. But Period 6 is -10% compared to Period 3. I already have caluclated the differences but just "in Total" not on the materialgroups.

Comment: In my understanding you have a flat excel file. If it's so, you can use like `CALCULATE(SUM([Budget]);ALLEXCEPT([Materialgroups]))` With a Calculate() you get a row context, then you change it by opening the table with removing all filters except the value that you have in a Materialgroups column at the current row. I cant garantee that exactly this code will work, but, hope, you got the idea.

Comment: I think I was a little inaccurate with my description. But the code delivers another important insight, not exactly what i was looking for, but maybe i can figure it out on my own. because now i have like the "total sum" of a certain materialgroup in front of me but not the percentages. Something like =DIVIDE[Budget of certain Materialgroup in row 1];filter([Period]=3;[Budget in Total];BLANK())-1 (disclaimer: the code is not correct yet!)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.